# problems with changing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 a models

```
-product (width an boolean attribute named "active")
-variant
```

product has many variants

so if i do this:

```
p = Product.first
p.active = false
p.save

p = Product.first
p.active = true
v = p.variants.first
v.product.active is equal to false
```

why?

How can i read the last setted active's value  without save the table product?

thanks

I'm using ruby ree 1.8.7

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this at the moment in Rails 3.0, although it may be possible in Rails 3.1 due to the identity map. You will have to save the object to the database before you can read the attribute like that.

Comment: Can you point me to some site about this in Rails 3.1? Thanks!

Comment: A recent railscast talks about it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview